# apply does not result in the same vector like replaced for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, sapply

the function "trio" exemplifies a function with numerous calculations, that takes in certain columns from a data frame (df) and three values for the calculations:

```
# example: data
df <- data.frame(C1= c(1,2,3,4,5,6),C2= c(5,4,3,2,1,6),C3= c(9,1,5,2,7,4))

# example: function
trio  <- function(a,b,c){
             df2 <- df %>%
             mutate(., 
                 df$C1 * a,
                 df$C2 * b,
                 df$C2 * c 
              ) 
df2$calc <- df2[3] * df2[4]/df2[5]
max(df2$calc)
}
```

to find which value combination results in the best output (= max(df2$calc) a matrix with value combinations is created:

```
pp <- expand.grid(parameter_A = round(seq(min, max, length.out = count),3),
                  parameter_B = round(seq(min, max, length.out = count),3), 
                  parameter_C = round(seq(min, max, length.out = count),3))
```

To replace the for loop

```
max.all<- c()
for(w in 1:nrow(pp)){
    max.all[w] <-  findWinZ(pp[w,1],pp[w,2],pp[w,3])  
    }
```

I aimed to use one function of the Apply-Family (sapply, lapply), e.g.

```
Version1: res2 <- sapply(pp, function(a,b,c)  findWinZ(length(pp[,1]),length(pp[,2]),length(pp[,3])))  

Version: res3 <- sapply(pp, function(a,b,c)  length(findWinZ(pp[w,1],pp[w,2],pp[w,3])))
```

Alas, the outcome of the apply() loops is wrong. What I need is the vector with all results, i.e. the same output as I get from the for loop. 
Please, can anyone correct my apply() code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you want to​ iterate through a sequence of multiple arguments. I think you want to use `mapply` in this case.

Comment: Yes `mapply` seems the appropriate `apply`-family function to use here.  Please take greater care to make your examples reproducible in the future.

Comment: Will test this option and compare performance. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is how to rewrite the for loop as an sapply, how about:

```
res4 <- sapply(1:nrow(pp), function(w) findWinZ(pp[w,1],pp[w,2],pp[w,3]))
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution was so simple. At least, I got close. Interestingly the apply() version is not much faster than the for loop (timed with ptm <- proc.time() & proc.time() - ptm. Thanks again!